# Change a label position while scrollview is scrolling

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I have a label outside of a scrollview. I want to move the label from left to right of screen and vice versa when scrollview scrolling up and down.I wrote this code and it works when scrollview is scrolling in normal speed and when it scrolls very fast the label x position changes very slowly. How I can do that for all scrollview scrolling speeds?

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView!) {

    let offset = scrollView.contentOffset.y
    let imahey = view.convert(placeImgview.frame, from:scrollview).origin.y + placeImgview.frame.width
    print(offset)
    let ratio: CGFloat = (-offset*1.0 / placeImgview.frame.height)
    topBarView.alpha =  -ratio
    if placeName.frame.origin.x < -20 {
        placeName.center = CGPoint(x: placeName.center.x - 3*ratio, y: placeName.center.y + ratio/1.5)
    }
    if (self.lastContentOffset > scrollView.contentOffset.y) {

            placeName.center = CGPoint(x: placeName.center.x + 6*ratio, y: placeName.center.y - 2*ratio)
        if offset == -20 {
            placeName.frame.origin.x = -view.frame.width/2
            placeName.frame.origin.y = 60
        }

    }

    self.lastContentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the problem is that the faster you scroll, the larger the "gap" gets inbetween scrollViewDidScroll events.

You probably should consider to move around your label using UIView.animate... that would create a more consistent experience because the animation always has the same speed.
This way you could apply the animation using CGAffineTransform(translationX: , y: )
depending if your contentOffset.y passes a given threshold, whenever that label should appear or disappear.

Comment: thanks.Using CGAffineTransform(translationX: , y: ) solved the problem.